# Preventing shutdown/startup freezes on Linux Mint/Ubuntu with NVIDIA Optimus system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, intel-graphics, optimus

I'm at my wit's end with this, I've been grappling with a variant of this problem for about a year now.
Essentially I have an NVIDIA Optimus laptop, and when switching to the Intel GPU via NVIDIA Prime, the machine would just freeze upon logging out. The only way to boot the system from then onwards was to use nomodeset.

I've made some progress based on hours of research. Currently I have a clean installation of 18.2. The first thing I did was update the kernel to 4.10.0-35-generic, which at the time was the latest that showed as a recommended update in Update Manager. Then I installed the NVIDIA and Intel Microcode drivers via the Driver Manager. Booting the system with the NVIDIA GPU selected by default, I switched to Intel and the machine froze on logout, and refused to load the login screen after reboot. Business as usual. It should be noted that I doubt the kernel update is causing this as I had identical behaviour with the default kernel. In fact it has been suggested that the 4.10 kernel might fix some of these issues, but not in my case.
I then decided to boot again with the nomodeset option and was able to reach a desktop. Once this was done I installed the Intel GPU drivers using [this guide](https://mintguide.org/system/73-intel-linux-graphics-drivers-installer-for-linux.html). Everything was successful, but I still cannot boot without disabling hardware acceleration. It gets past the splash screen, and then hangs with this output on the screen, and will not respond to anything other than a forced shutdown with the power button.

```
[    8.836398] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 timeout
[    8.836446] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
```

My laptop's Bluetooth has no hardware switch so I cannot disable it. Sometimes, with the old kernel, I would have a similar message on shutdown if running the Intel GPU.

`inxi -Fxz` output (with nomodeset)

```
System:    Host: kyle-mint Kernel: 4.10.0-35-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
       Desktop: Cinnamon 3.4.6 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3)
       Distro: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
Machine:   System: PC Specialist Limited (portable) product: N15_17RF
       Mobo: CLEVO model: N15_17RF
       Bios: American Megatrends v: 1.05.02 date: 01/04/2016
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-6440HQ (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
       flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 20736
       clock speeds: max: 3500 MHz 1: 879 MHz 2: 833 MHz 3: 800 MHz
       4: 893 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Skylake Integrated Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0
       Card-2: NVIDIA GM206M [GeForce GTX 965M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
       Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: fbdev (unloaded: vesa) FAILED: intel,nouveau
       Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
       GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 256 bits)
       GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
       driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-35-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 02:00.0
       IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
       Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
Controller
       driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.1
       IF: enp3s0f1 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 878.2GB (1.6% used)
       ID-1: /dev/sda model: BIWIN_SSD size: 128.0GB
       ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD7500BPKX size: 750.2GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 28G used: 5.7G (22%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
       ID-2: /boot size: 276M used: 121M (46%) fs: ext2 dev: /dev/sda1
       ID-3: /home size: 275G used: 125M (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb6
       ID-4: swap-1 size: 8.19GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdb7
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 65.0C mobo: N/A
       Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 213 Uptime: 2 min Memory: 951.9/7899.8MB
       Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
       Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

The guys at the Linux Mint forums advised me to try [this](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/3#TOC-Improve-video-performance-for-Intel-graphics), but to no avail.
Is there anything else I might be able to try? Would I have better luck with vanilla Ubuntu as opposed to Linux Mint, or even a completely different distro?
I do not have the ability to switch off one of the GPUs in the BIOS for diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried installing [bumblebee](https://bumblebee-project.org/)? It basically handles the 'switching' between the two video drivers that "Optimus" offers.

Comment: Would this be installed in tandem with NVIDIA Prime? I had briefly explored bumblebee when I was using Mint 17.x but with no luck at all. Bearing in mind that I'm not sure this will solve the fact that I cannot boot with hardware acceleration if I'm using the intel GPU - a nicer bit of software to manage the NVIDIA GPU doesn't sound like it would solve that particular problem.

Comment: Update: No luck at all. Performed a clean install of Mint 18.2, and followed [link](https://www.pcsuggest.com/nvidia-optimus-ubuntu/) to get bumblebee installed. Same issue if trying to boot normally, and if I use the `nomodeset` boot option the machine just freezes on the splash screen (removing `quiet splash` subsequently produces no output, just a black screen). The intel GPU is just playing havoc with me, it seems.